# Books on color science

Tags: color, color-theory, reference-request

I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask, but I'm currently working on an automatic color scheme creating tool and the only sources I have found on this topic are very loosely tied with computational color science (I understand that there is a lot of subjectivity in the notion of color schemes in general).

My question is: are there any sources that cover the topic of color schemes or color generation in a more in-depth/mathematical way that I could use as a reference?

Comment: There are two topics here. Perceptual vs Mathematical. Color scheme is a psicological topic, you can call psicology a non exact sience. Not barely exact as mathematics for sure. But if that has a background statistical study, you can have mathematics on the background.

Comment: Color theory is not same as color science. Yes human senses are quite well studied and unlike what @Rafael says its pretty exact since we can actually do measurments and experiments that dont rely on psychology to deduce the system as well as actually disect and measure real input.

Comment: Anyway my point is that color science tells us how senses work... Color theory on the otherhand tells you about how to artistically choose colors. So are you sure you want a book on color science.

Comment: This subject is pretty broad. I counted over 45 books in my own library on the subject. Broadly speaking, searching "Michel Chevreul" and the "Colour Wheel" should bring up the lion's share of theory on the issue of colour harmony.

Comment: @joojaa, thanks for your input. Let me revise my question then: are there any sources on Computational Color? I understand the color wheel and the intuition behind scheme generation, I want to know whether there is more to it than just hue angles.

Comment: Please consider upvoting/following the StackExchange Color Theory site: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110687/color-theory

Answer (score 1):

You could check these if you haven't already:

- Alexis Van Hurkman: Look Book Creative Grading Techniques
- DaVinci Resolve 10 Manual: Free book
- Steve Hullfish: The Art & Technique of Digital Color Correction
- Encyclopedia of Color Science and Technology
- Günter Wyszecki, Walter Stanley Stiles: Color Science